# Jouer les / aux élèves modèles

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Je n’ai pas envie de jouer **aux** élèves modèles.
>
> Je n’ai pas envie de jouer **les** élèves modèles.

À mon avis, les deux variantes sont possibles, mais la deuxième est plus courante. Est-ce correct ?

> En partic. Être spécialisé dans un emploi. *Jouer les amoureux, les*
> *coquettes, les ingénues* ([cnrtl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer))
>
> Feindre un sentiment, simuler une attitude. *Jouer l'étonné, les héros,*
> *les incompris, les victimes; jouer l'étonnement. Je sais bien que je*
> *ne suis pas taillé pour jouer les amoureux* (Leclercq, Prov. dram.,
> Scène double, 1835, 1, p. 346). *En la trouvant morte dans son lit,*
> *Hilperik joua la surprise et l'affliction, il fit même semblant de*
> *verser des larmes, et, quelques jours après, il épousa Fredegonde*
> (Thierry, Récits mérov., t. 1, 1840, p. 357). *Si tu ne soupçonnes plus*
> *ton père, si personnellement tu ne lui en veux plus, ce n'est pas à*
> *toi de jouer les justiciers* (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954, p. 135) ([cnrtl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer))

Answer (score 4):

Il ne s'agit pas que d'être plus courant ou pas. Le sens est sensiblement différent entre les deux expressions.

Avec ***jouer à***, il s'agit simplement d'un jeu, d'une distraction : *jouer au gendarme et aux voleur* alors qu'avec ***jouer les*** il ne s'agit plus nécessairement d'un amusement mais plutôt de feindre être ce qu'on n'est pas, parfois à des fins de tromperie.

Comment: Merci, c'est ce que je pensais, je n'étais pas sûre. Mais la nuance entre les deux pourrait aussi être subtile. _Je joue la Bad Girl._ = Je m'amuse à me comporter comme Bad Girl, il s'agit plutôt d'un jeu. _Je joue la Bad Girl._ = 1. Je fais semblant, je ne le suis pas en réalité. 2. Être Bad Girl est mon "rôle" et je le montre à tout le monde.

Comment: Oui, les deux sens ne sont pas toujours disjoints.

Comment: [exemple](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/jouer-au-le-gendarme.3044724/) Il y a une explication ici, mais ce n'est pas vraiment clair pour moi.

Comment: C'est un troisième sens: *Dans la pièce c'est moi qui joue Cyrano.*

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Je préfère nettement la définition du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seigneur): *− Souvent péj. Faire le, jouer au (grand) seigneur. Faire l'important; dépenser beaucoup, par magnificence ou ostentation, avec grandeur.*

Comment: Réf. l'[exemple](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/jouer/45008) au Larousse. Je trouve ça plus clair aussi. Larousse auraient dû mettre ça dans leur section _expressions_ plutôt que dans les définitions, je sais pas. C'est comme _jouer l'important_...