# Le choix du nombre des compléments des syntagmes avec le verbe « jouer » découlant de l'idée de rôle ?

Tags: usage, pluriel, locutions, transitivité

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44471/26366) on a discuté du choix de préposition et des emplois transitif direct et indirect du verbe [*jouer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer) découlant de la notion de *tenir un rôle*. Ce qui m'intéresse c'est le nombre des noms qui servent de complément au verbe dans ces syntagmes.

Au TLFi, on passe de « *jouer le personnage de Tartuffe* et, p. ell., *jouer Tartuffe* » à « être spécialisé dans un emploi. *Jouer les amoureux, les coquettes, les ingénues* » puis encore, plus loin « feindre un sentiment, simuler une attitude. *Jouer l'étonné, les héros, les incompris, les victimes; jouer l'étonnement* ». C'est suivi d'un emploi transitif indirect : « Emploi trans. indir. *Jouer à l'indispensable, au généreux; jouer à la vertu.* » et finalement dans ce découpage on présente « Affecter d'être, se donner l'air de. *Jouer l'homme important.* », incluant un exemple avec *barons* et un autre transitif indirect (*à la châtelaine*).

Par exemple pour l'emploi avec le substantif [*ingénu*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ing%C3%A9nu) pour « franchise innocente et naïve » on donne « *Faire l'ingénu, jouer les ingénues* » (TLFi). On a vu *étonné* au singulier et *héros, incompris, victimes* au pluriel etc. [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/jouer/45008) présente un exemple « chercher à se faire passer pour quelqu'un que l'on n'est pas : Jouer au grand seigneur » et au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jouer#Verbe) (section *dérivés*) on a *jouer les étonnés*, *les durs* etc.

Y a-t-il une logique dans le choix du nombre du complément pour ce genre d'acception du verbe *jouer* ; ou y a-t-il usage particulier pour chacun des substantifs avec ce verbe, est-ce selon que c'est plus figé ou non ? Y a-t-il une différence de sens entre l'emploi au singulier et au pluriel et lequel est le plus courant (par exemple avec *héros*, si c'est un bon prototype) ?